# Creating an imovie-like frame strip with pinch/zoom

Tags: ios, ios6, avfoundation, mpmediaplayercontroller

Does anyone know how apple created the filmstrip of frame-by-frame from a video? I'd like to implement similar functionality, showing a frame every 5 sec or so, with a pinch/zoom functionality that either increases resolution (frame every 1 sec) or decreases it (frame every 10 sec)..

A screenshot of what I mean is here;

[image]

I've been looking at AVFoundation and MediaPlayer frameworks, but not coming up with anything.. are they using an internal api or something?

If anyone's got code samples they can share, this iOS newbie will be grateful!